# how to transfer data from controller to view

Tags: asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

HomeController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int searchtext)
{
    var data = (from pm in db.ProductMasters
                join shi in db.SuppliersHotelsInfoes
                    on pm.ProductID equals shi.LocHotelID
                where shi.SearchID == searchtext
                select new {pm.ProductId,pm.Image,shi.HotelName,shi.HotelPrice}).ToList().Take(10);
    ViewBag.Data = data;
        return View();
}
```

Transfering the data to the view

```
<% try { %>
<tr><td>
    <% foreach(var item in ViewBag.Data){ %>
    <img alt="" src="<%= item. %>" />
        </td><%} %>            <% foreach(var item in ViewBag.Data) { %>
    <td><%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => "")%></td>
    <td><%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => "")%> </td>
    <td><%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => "")%></td>
</tr>
<%} }%>
<%catch(Exception ex){ }%>
```

Here, how to get the values in "var item"

Comment: Why don't you use Model? Create a new ViewModel and pass it.

Comment: I have an entity model

Answer (score 0):

You really should use a ViewModel, I can't remember last time I used the `ViewBag`

I'm also going to use Razor here, its syntax is much more terse. You don't need to use `DisplayFor` if you're just presenting the data:

```
@foreach(var item in ViewBag.Data){ 
 <tr>
   <td><img alt="" src="@item.Image" /><td>
   <td>@item.ProductId</td>
   <td>@item.HotelName</td>
   <td>@item.HotelPrice</td>
  </tr>
}
```

Comment: i got exception when i use like this

Comment: The exception being what, exactly?

Comment: "'object' does not contain a definition for 'Image'"

Comment: is there any way for which  can take @item["image"]

Comment: Put a breakpoint in this loop and see what properties `item` has.

Comment: i did like that.. getting all items, what i took from query

Comment: In query when i took select new{}.. i got this.. System.Linq.Enumerable.TakeIterator<<>f__AnonymousType3<string,string,decimal?,string>>}

and when i took select pm, then i got i like this



{MblSearchApp.Models.ProductMaster}